# Google drive API - Getting the parent folder with file_id?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Google Drive topic
Is there a way to get the "folder name" with the file_id or the folder_id?

Comment: I can understand that the folder name is retrieved by the folder ID. But I cannot understand that the folder name is retrieved by the file ID. Can I ask you about it? By the way, what language do you want to achieve your goal using? By the way, in order to retrieve the folder name by the folder ID, you can use the method of Files: get in Drive API. You can test it at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done in a single call its needs to be two. First you find the parent id of the file id you have then you need to request the name of the folder using the parent id that was returned to you from the first call.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FileId]?fields=parents
```

Will give you the parent id of the folder that the file is currently in

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[ParentId]?fields=name
```

Will give you the name of the parent folder

Answer (score 6):

> This can not be done in a single call its needs to be two. First you find the parent id of the file id you have then you need to request the name of the folder using the parent id that was returned to you from the first call.
>
> `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FileId]?fields=parents`
>
> Will give you the parent id of the folder that the file is currently in
>
> `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[ParentId]?fields=name`
>
> Will give you the name of the parent folder

---

Here is an easy example made with *"node.js"*

We are searching for a filename *"123"*, once found search for a parent id

**Callbacks way:**

```js
function getParentID(auth) {

    const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v3',
        auth
    });

    drive.files.list({
        q: "name = '123'"
    }, (err, res) => {

        if (err) return console.log('#1001 - The API returned an error: ' + err);

        const fileId = res.data.files[0].id;
        console.log("File ID : ", fileId);

        drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            fields: "parents"
        }, (err, res) => {

            if (err) return console.log('#1002 - The API returned an error:' + err);

            console.log("Parent folder ID :", res.data.parents[0])

        })

    });

}
```

**Promises way:**

```js
function getParentID2(auth) {

    const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v3',
        auth
    });

    drive.files.list({
        q: "name = '123'"
    }).then((res) => {

        const fileId = res.data.files[0].id;
        console.log("File ID : ", fileId);

        drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            fields: "parents"
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log("Parent folder ID :", res.data.parents[0])
        })

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)  
    })

}
```

**Output:**

`File ID :  2xU_zgmOcjOIterprt91wibEEKU8fuNI-yZuBcgvEFjY
Parent folder ID : 2KQve4H24jlgJKcywGRBJaOnTK2tDLZgR`

### References:

- [Google Drive API - Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) - Here you can find node.js quickstart guide to be able to reproduce the snippet from above
- [Google Drive API - drive.files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Google Drive API - drive.files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: thows error - Invalid field selection parents